# read-char behaving unpredictably

Tags: prompt

In a nutshell, the problem I'm having is that evaluating the expression

```
(read-char "some prompt")
```

*sometimes* fails to show the specified prompt (but works as expected otherwise).

Unfortunately, from my perspective, the problem shows up *completely* randomly.  I'm sure it is not really random; it just looks this way to me, because I have *no idea* of what's going on.

As a result of this complete unpredictability, I can't guarantee that the silly example below will reproduce the problem.  I show it only to describe the setting.

```
(defun foo (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((read-1-char (lambda () (string (read-char "Type one char" t)))))
    (let ((bar
           (cond ((equal arg '(4)) (funcall read-1-char))
                 (t (error "foo: the C-u prefix is required")))))
     (message ">%s<" (prin1-to-string bar)))))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M") 'foo)
```

The *intended* behavior of this code is that, if one types `C-u C-c M`, the message `Type one char` will appear in the minibuffer; if one then types, say, `x`, the message `>"x"<` will be displayed.

In some cases, however, after typing `C-u C-c M`, instead of `Type one char`, the "message" in the minibuffer is just `C-u C-c M-`.  (The subsequent behavior remains the same; e.g., if the user then types `x`, the message `>"x"<` does get displayed.)

Comment: `setq`  `echo-keystrokes` to 0 to disable showing unfinished commands seems help, while let-binding this variable doesn't help. Or, use `(message nil)` to clear echo area's contents before invoking `read-char`.

Comment: It has been reported in [#21102](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21102) in July this year, but doesn't get any response yet.